# RewriteRule on litespeed question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, litespeed

My rule works good when I access **http://domain.com/example** . The Query looks good etc.

When I visis **http://domain.com** the index.php does not load, seem that a blank redirect is done, **http://domain.com/city.php?q=**

How can I get the index.php to load instead of a the Rewrite kicking in...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|jpg|gif|png|jar|js|html|htm|php)$
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /city.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```